# Guava LoadingCache with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: rest, caching, kotlin, guava, ktor

I'm using Guava's [`Loading Cache`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) to cache the results of HTTP requests. Kotlin / KTOR provides an [HTTP Client Library](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client.html#parallel-requests) based on coroutines (i.e. non-blocking HTTP requests).

My problem is that the Loading Cache has no idea about `suspend`ing functions. The `load` function that I pass to the loading cache **cannot** suspend. So I am forced to do the HTTP requests inside a `runBlocking` call, eliminating the benefit of non-blocking calls completely.

My question is: is there a better way? How would you implement caching of coroutine results?

Comment: Consider using [Caffeine's](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) `AsyncLoadingCache` and [convert](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) the coroutine to a `CompleteableFuture`.

Comment: I found a nice solution using Caffeine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439143/4618331

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put `Deferred` into guava's cache from coroutines `async { ... }`

Something like this

```
LoadingCache<Key, Deferred<Value>> = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    // ...
    .build(CacheLoader<Key, Deferred<Value>> { key ->
        someScope.async { computeMyValueSuspend(key) }
    })
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I think that might work, thanks!

Comment: would defining a single coroutine scope, like `val someScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)`, which I create once per cache be a suitable way to handle coroutine scope?