# How do I use an async cache with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, caching, kotlin-coroutines, caffeine

I have a Kotlin JVM server application using coroutines and I need to put a cache in front of a non-blocking network call. I figure I can use a Caffeine [`AsyncLoadingCache`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncLoadingCache.html) to get the non-blocking cache behaviour I need. The [`AsyncCacheLoader`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncCacheLoader.html) interface I would need to implement uses `CompletableFuture`. Meanwhile, the method I want to call to load the cache entries is a `suspend` function.

I can bridge the gap like this:

```
abstract class SuspendingCacheLoader<K, V>: AsyncCacheLoader<K, V> {
    abstract suspend fun load(key: K): V

    final override fun asyncLoad(key: K, executor: Executor): CompletableFuture<V> {
        return GlobalScope.async(executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
            load(key)
        }.asCompletableFuture()
    }
}
```

This will run the `load` function on the provided `Executor` (by default, the `ForkJoinPool`), which from the point of view of Caffeine is the correct behaviour.

However, I know that I should try to [avoid using GlobalScope to launch coroutines](https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc).

I considered having my `SuspendingCacheLoader` implement [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html) and manage its own coroutine context. But `CoroutineScope` is intended to be implemented by objects with a managed lifecycle. Neither the cache nor the `AsyncCacheLoader` has any lifecycle hooks. The cache owns the `Executor` and the `CompletableFuture` instances, so it already controls the lifecycle of the loading tasks that way. I can't see that having the tasks be owned by a coroutine context would add anything, and I'm worried that I wouldn't be able to correctly close the coroutine context after the cache stopped being used.

Writing my own asynchronous caching mechanism would be prohibitively difficult, so I'd like to integrate with the Caffeine implementation if I can.

Is using `GlobalScope` the right approach to implement `AsyncCacheLoader`, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some thought I've come up with a much simpler solution that I think uses coroutines more idiomatically.

The approach works by using [`AsyncCache.get(key, mappingFunction)`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncCache.html#get-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-), instead of implementing an `AsyncCacheLoader`. However, it ignores the `Executor` that the cache is configured to use, following the advice of some of the other answers here.

```kotlin
class SuspendingCache<K, V>(private val asyncCache: AsyncCache<K, V>) {
    suspend fun get(key: K): V = supervisorScope {
        getAsync(key).await()
    }

    private fun CoroutineScope.getAsync(key: K) = asyncCache.get(key) { k, _ ->
        future { 
            loadValue(k) 
        }
    }

    private suspend fun loadValue(key: K): V = TODO("Load the value")
}
```

Note that this depends on `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` for the `future` coroutine builder and the `await()` function.

I think ignoring the `Executor` is probably the right choice. As @Kiskae points out, the cache will use the `ForkJoinPool` by default. Choosing to use that rather than the default coroutine dispatcher is probably not useful. However, it would be easy to use it if we wanted to, by changing the `getAsync` function:

```kotlin
private fun CoroutineScope.getAsync(key: K) = asyncCache.get(key) { k, executor ->
    future(executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()) { 
        loadValue(k) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great for `get`, but how to invalidate a key?

Comment: To invalidate a key, you could add another method that calls through to `asyncCache.synchronous().invalidate(key)`. You can do the same for any other modifications you need to make to the underlying cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a blocking method. It could be dispatched to IO pool though.

Comment: Be careful, if `coroutineContext` is used instead of `supervisorContext`, this will run into problems with exceptions. I feel it is safer to use `GlobalScope`

Answer (score 3):

> The cache owns the Executor and the CompletableFuture instances, so it already controls the lifecycle of the loading tasks that way.

This is not true, the documentation on `Caffeine` specifies that it uses a user-provided `Executor` or `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` if none is provided. This means that there is no default lifecycle.

Regardless directly calling `GlobalScope` seems like the wrong solution because there is no reason to hardcode a choice. Simply provide a `CoroutineScope` through the constructor and use `GlobalScope` as an argument while you don't have an explicit lifecycle for the cache to bind to.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the clarification about the Caffeine executor. I like the idea of accepting a `CoroutineScope` in the constructor. If I were to end up passing in a `CoroutineScope` from the wider application, what kind of benefits could that give me? I imagine that within the `AsyncCacheLoader` I'd want to override both the `Dispatcher` (using the provided `Executor`) and the `Job` (since it wouldn't make sense for cache loading failures to propagate outside of the cache). Once that's done, it seems like there wouldn't be much of the original context left.

Comment: I don't see what benefits you'd get from a coroutine scope passed in since you're clearly working outside the coroutine world and your callers don't have it at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution. Replace the K, V notation with your type.

```
    val cache = Caffeine.newBuilder().buildAsync<K, V> { key: K, _ ->
      val future = CompletableFuture<V>()

      launch {
        val result = someAwaitOperation(key)
        future.complete(result)
      }

      future
    }
```

Comment: no need to do all this since a future creator is already available

Answer (score 1):

Suggest extension method like this

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <K: Any, V: Any> Caffeine<Any, Any>.suspendingLoadingCache(
    crossinline suspendedLoader: suspend (key: K) -> V
): AsyncLoadingCache<K, V> =
    buildAsync { key, executor: Executor ->
        CoroutineScope(executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()).future {
            suspendedLoader(key)
        }
    }
```

Not recommand `GlobalScope`, use `CoroutineScope(executor.asCoroutineDispatcher())`

`future` method is defined in `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` module

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Define an extension function of `CoroutineVerticle`

```
fun <K, V> CoroutineVerticle.buildCache(configurator: Caffeine<Any, Any>.() -> Unit = {}, loader: suspend CoroutineScope.(K) -> V) = Caffeine.newBuilder().apply(configurator).buildAsync { key: K, _ ->
    // do not use cache's executor
    future {
        loader(key)
    }
}
```

Create our cache within `CoroutineVerticle`

```
val cache : AsyncLoadingCache<String, String> = buildCache({
  maximumSize(10_000)
  expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
}) { key ->
    // load data and return it
    delay(1000)
    "data for key: $key"
}
```

Use the cache

```
suspend fun doSomething() {
    val data = cache.get('key').await()

    val future = cache.get('key2')
    val data2 = future.await()
}
```