# How can I get a return value from a Coroutine Scope in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines, caffeine

I'm building a cache using Caffeine and Kotlin. I have something like this:

```
private val esCache: Cache<EsRequestParam, EsResponse> = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .refreshAfterWrite(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build<EsRequestParam, EsResponse> {
        runBlocking {
            sendRequest(it)
        }
    }


private suspend fun sendRequest(requestParams: EsRequestParam): EsResponse? {
        val result = client
                .sendJsonObjectAwait(
                        JsonObject(
                            buildPostBody(requestParams)
                        ))
                .bodyAsJson(EsResponse::class.java)
        esCache.put(requestParams, result)
        return result
    }
```

Since I'm using Vertx too, I know it has an event loop that can be blocked and brake my application. And `runBlocking` is bringing me this problem. So I need to exchange this `runBlocking` to some other Vertx resource or maybe a `GlobalScope.launch(vertx.dispacther())`. Then I could avoid the blocking event.
The problem is: I don't know which Vertx resource I could use and I can't use `GlobalScope.launch` since it returns a Job, not the returning value from `sendRequest` function.
Any ideas?
Ps.: since `sendRequest` is a suspended fun, I can only call it from a coroutine or other suspended fun :(

Comment: Perhaps try using AsyncLoadingCache can convert between futures and coroutines?

Comment: I don’t know what Caffeine is, but it is pretty much always wrong to use `runBlocking` anywhere except at the top level in a `main` function.

Comment: There is a prior [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439143/19450) that you might find helpful.